# How to hide Picture size column in an Asset Library -SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, image-display, asset-library

Working in SharePoint 2013, I created an Asset library to display wall arts/ paintings with an Arts Dimensions column. The default display template shows 'Picture Size' column which is a part of Image Content type. I would like to hide it. 
Can anyone recommend if it is possible to hide Picture Size column in an asset library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use JavaScript to hide the picture size for tiles in Thumbnail view.

Add the following jQuery code into a Content/Script Editor Web Part in Thumbnails.aspx page.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox").each(function () {
                $(this).find("ul > li:eq(1)").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Joanna, I was actually looking for an out of the box solution but it looks like that is not possible.